# bootstrapTable doesn't refresh with the newly created json

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Everything worked fine until we transfered the app to new domain. Now it simply doesn't refresh the table with newly generated json.

```
$('input[name^=\"tbl-\"]').on('change', function() {
        let elem = $(this)
        $.post(
            '/analytics/admin/site/index',
            {index: $(this).data('index'), value: $(this).val()}
        )
        .done(function(data){
            let table = elem.next('.example').find('table')
            table.eq(1).bootstrapTable('refresh')
        })
    })
```

Refresh action is executed (the form blings when its refreshed also no errors in the console). Tried with `console.log` in the `.done()` and request are successful. No errors in the network tab as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the markup for your table, it's hard to know how you're expecting to update the data contained therein. If you're expecting it to be filled with the `data` value that's returned from your POST, I think you'll need to set the data option:

```
    .done(function(data){
        let table = elem.next('.example').find('table')
        table.eq(1).bootstrapTable({data: data})
        table.eq(1).bootstrapTable('refresh')
    })
```

See: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/from-data.html

If you're instead using the `data-url` attribute on your table, you may need to check to see if that URL is still valid with your new domain.